# Turn off file and printer sharing

Tags: wireless-networking

When using a ''Public connection'' in Windows 7 with a public wifi spot, if i go into Advanced sharing settings and click to turn off ''Network Discovery'' and ''File and Printer sharing'' and then click save changes they never stay turned off.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart after changing the settings ?
A quick way to cut it all down is to run `net stop server` command form a cmd prompt.
You can run it with 'start' instead of 'stop' if you even need to reactive it.

The long and politically-correct way to remove F&P sharing is to go to Start , Control Panel , Network and Internet , Network and Sharing Center and click the link for "Local Area Connection" or "Wireless Network Connection" ,  "Properties",  select "File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks" and click the "Uninstall" button. Answer Yes and close everything.

Comment: Thanks alot Overmind. I have the Properties list in front of me now, but it's showing along list of checked items with the install and uninstall buttons below. Dumb question, but if all are checked how do i select only ''File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks'' to uninstall? Thnx

Comment: Only the selected item will uninstall, it is not relevant if it is checked or not. It gets blue when selected: https://kb.uwplatt.edu/images/group159/30119/LANProperties.png